# How do I create a capped array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Are capped arrays created automatically everytime you add an array to a document, or is there a command you must enter?

Here is the command for capped collections:

```
db.createCollection( "log", { capped: true, size: 100000 } )
```

From what I read, you only have to use the `$slice` command. Can anyone confirm this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Try using the [`$slice`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/) operator for your capped array, as explained in this [post](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/58782996153/push-to-sorted-array) about MongoDB 2.4.

Such as with `$slice: [capValue]` in your query.

> Mongo maintains the array in natural order and trims the array to 5
>   elements. It is possible to specify to slice from the start of the
>   array or the end of the array by using positive or negative integers
>   with $slice.

Hope that helps!